# Mistake in my CodeIgniter sql join query

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

So I have been lookin for mistake for a while, but still can't find it.

Here is the code -

```
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('friendRequests');
        $this->db->where(array('friendRequests.status' => 1, 'users.status' => 1)); 
        $this->db->or_where(array('friendRequests.senderId' => $this->session->userdata('userId'), 'friendRequests.receiverId' => $this->session->userdata('userId'))); 
        $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = '.$this->session->userdata('userId'));             
        $query = $this->db->get();
```

It provides me this error -

```
Unknown column '1' in 'on clause'

SELECT *
  FROM (`friendRequests`) 
  JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `1`
 WHERE `friendRequests`.`status` = 1
   AND `users`.`status` = 1 
    OR `friendRequests`.`senderId` = '1' 
    OR `friendRequests`.`receiverId` = '1'
```

Comment: Seems like you're building  a big project, than don't use `JOIN`

Comment: Hmm, could you please explain why?

Comment: Well, basically I will need to select data from other tables also, but I will need to check if the user is in friend with the other user. Basically, I must check if it's a friend (from friendRequests) and then pull out user data from users table.

Comment: When you get big, it will be complicated to manage tables from databases placed on different servers to `JOIN`. :)

Comment: @riwette You're suggesting that very large applications should never use JOINs?  That sounds incorrect to me..

Comment: @ExplosionPills Yes, and that's information from highload application consultant, also he suggests to use only simple commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an entry is surrounded in backticks it counts as a column even if it would not be one without the backtics.  It thinks that `1` is a column on the `JOIN` line because of this.

Apparently this is a product of the `join` method in CI.  You can fix it very easily by moving that condition to the `WHERE` clause.  There's no need for it to be in the `JOIN` clause.

Answer (score 0):

JOIN does not work that way; the syntax is:

```
JOIN 'tablename' ON 'tablename.field' = 'othertable.field'
```

If I had to assume you were trying to get a user's friend requests:

```
JOIN 'users' ON 'users'.'id' = 'friendRequests'.'receiverId'
```

Comment: That's not true.  What part of his JOIN syntax do you think is mistaken?

Comment: I've never seen JOIN table ON field = 1, I thought the whole point of a join was to bring two tables together on a common key?

Comment: In general it is, but it is still valid to say `field = "scalar"` in a `JOIN`.  You can put anything in `ON` that you can put in `WHERE` and vice versa (I think).  In fact, this is can be necessary when doing an exclusion via JOIN.